# How to delete data in MySQL from SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have few tables in MySQL and I wanted to delete data in those MySQL tables from SQL Server. Do we have any approach to perform it?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform Insert/Update/ Delete/ Select using Linked Server in the SQL Server. You just need to create MySQL LinkedServer and use Open Query.

Sample Query:

```
DELETE FROM OPENQUERY([MYSQL_LOCAL], 'SELECT user_id FROM d_portal.users' ) where user_id = 1;
```

MYSQL_LOCAL is a MySQL Linked Server. 
You can follow the below Article for better guidance.

https://www.sqlshack.com/mysql-query-t-sql-tutorial-for-sql-server/